# Will this PCI express card fit into any of these slots?

Tags: pci-express

Will this [PCI express card](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=549) …

[image]

… fit into any of these slots. [My motherboard](http://www.intel.com/Products/Desktop/Motherboards/DG41RQ/DG41RQ-overview.htm?) offers:

> - One PCI Express* x16 bus add-in card connector
> - Two PCI Conventional* bus connectors

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, technically, it should work, as long as you don't have another card in the PCIe x16 slot on that motherboard.  Though the PCIe x16 is usually used for graphics cards, the standard indicates that any PCIe card is supposed to be able to work in any PCIe slot which is that size or bigger.  The expansion card you show is a PCIe x1, which is supposed to work in a x1, x4, x8 or x16 slot.  But, as with all standards, support by motherboard and card may vary.

You can read more about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express.

Comment: Using a PCI-E x1 device in a x16 is a bit of a waste though. You'd be better off getting a PCI card and using that, IMO.

Comment: Agreed, it would be a huge waste of bandwidth in most cases, but it depends on what he intends to use that setup for.  If he has no need of a graphics card, but wants a cheap motherboard for a specific wireless network purpose, this would be sufficient.

Comment: I have this motherboard already. I just want to buy a Wireless adaptor for my desktop and it's available in 2 forms 1) PCIe 2) PCI

Comment: If you need a graphics card too and don't already have one, I would highly recommend, then, that you get the PCI version of the wireless card and save the PCIe slot for a graphics card.

Comment: I don't have graphic card and I don't need it I'm just happy with inbuilt graphics of Motherboard. I don't play game.

Comment: id still say get the pci one if you can. ironic name, also :)

Answer (score 2):

usually, yes. it'll go in the black one, which is a pcie 16x port. Even though it's a pcie1x card it should work. However not all motherboards support anything but video cards in the pci 16x slots, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture of the card shows a PCI express x1 card.
Your picture of the computer shows a PCI express x16 slot and two conventional PCI slots.

A PCI express x1 card will fit in a PCI express x16 slot. However from bitter experiance some systems will refuse to boot if you put a non-graphics card in the x16 slot. I'm not 100% sure what is happening but my guess would be that inserting the card disables the onboard graphics leaving the computer with no graphics and therefore unable to boot (graphics on PCs is considered core system hardware).

A PCI express card will NOT fit in a conventional PCI slot.